Jinja include got "TypeError: no loader for this environment specified"
Try to get sub html template with include
main.html:
<!-- main_template.html -->
<html>
<head><title>Main Template</title></head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome to the Main Template!</h1>
    <div>
        {{ content }}
    </div> 
    <div>
        {% include 'sub.html'  %} 
    </div>
     
</body>
</html>



sub.html
<div>
    <h2>This is the Sub Template.</h2>
    <p>It is included in the Main Template.</p>
</div>


main.py

from jinja2 import Template
base_html0 = open('main.html').read() 
tplt = Template(base_html0)

html = tplt.render(content='content123')

save_path = 'r2.html'
with open(save_path, 'w') as f:f.write(html) 



got err :
  File "<template>", line 12, in top-level template code
TypeError: no loader for this environment specified


1、replace the path to full path, err still
2、rm {% include 'tpf.html' %} , no err

This question is similar to: jinja2 load template from string: TypeError: no loader for this environment specified. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Jinja language doesn't specify how exactly the name sub.html, which you use in {% include %}  directive, will be translated to the loaded template. It is responsibility of the loader. You need to specify the one for make things work.
